# fluent nhibernate one to many collection, filtered by enum

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, one-to-many

I think I have a design issue here.

essentially I have a class called office

```
class Office
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Person> Managers { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Person> Developers { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Person> TeaMakers { get; set; }
}
```

and a class called Person

```
class Person
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual StaffType Type { get; set;}
    public virtual Office Office { get; set; }
}
```

and an enum called StaffType

```
public enum StaffType
{
   MANAGER,
   DEVELOPER,
   TEAMAKER
}
```

Mapping the Person table is easy:

```
public class PersonMap: ClassMap<Person>    
{

   public PersonMap()
   {
     Table("Person");
     Id(x => x.Id);
     Map(x => x.Name);
     References(x => x.Office).ForeignKey("Id").Not.Nullable()
     Map(x => x.Type).CustomType<StaffType>();
   }
}
```

but i am stumped on the office map. how to i get the map to use the enum to filter the 3 lists?

if i do this:

```
public class OfficeMap: ClassMap<Office>    
{
    public static string TableName = "Office";
    public static string MappingColumn = TableName + "Id";


   public OfficeMap()
   {
      Table(TableName);
      Id(x => x.Id);
      Map(x = x.Code);

      HasMany(x => x.Managers)
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Fetch.Select()
            .Inverse().KeyColumn(MappingColumn);

     HasMany(x => x.Developers)
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Fetch.Select()
            .Inverse().KeyColumn(MappingColumn);

    HasMany(x => x.TeaMakers)
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Fetch.Select()
            .Inverse().KeyColumn(MappingColumn);
   }
}
```

fluency won't have the foggiest idea how to split the 3 collections up by the StaffType enum

Thanks for the help

Extra note: the Person table's Type field allways gets mapped as an int.

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate supports filtering as a part of the mapping. Please, read here more [6.2. Mapping a Collection](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-mapping).

The trick is to add more SQL into the mapping. In fact, some WHERE Condition, to be evaluated during the collection load. Small extract from the documentation:

```
<map // or <set or <bag ...
    name="propertyName"                                         (1)
    table="table_name"                                          (2)
    ...
    where="arbitrary sql where condition"                       (9)
```

And the description of the WHERE:

> where (optional) specify an arbitrary SQL WHERE condition to be used
>   when retrieving or removing the collection (useful if the collection
>   should contain only a subset of the available data)

In your case, the fluent syntax is similar: `...Where("MyColumn = 'myValue' ");`

A draft for your solution:

```
...
HasMany(x => x.Managers)
   .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
   .Fetch.Select()
   .Inverse().KeyColumn(MappingColumn)
   .Where("Type = 1") // the Column name in the Person table
;                     // and the value 1 as the enum of the Manager
...
// The same for the others
```

Answer (score 0):

I would model this as a simple one-to-many (Office has many Person) and add an extension method to `IEnumerable<Person>` to filter by StaffType. If needed, you can encapsulate access to the Person collection through `AddManager` etc. methods that enforce business rules.